# Simple php syntax error, needs fixing

Tags: php, echo

I have a code that can get me the `category_id` of an item. This is the code:

```
<?php echo lavada_category_id() ; ?>
```

I want to know how I can add this code. Inside this, I want to replace the number 2 in here;

```
<?php lavada_query_item("category=2");?>
```

with:

```
<?php echo lavada_category_id() ; ?>
```

I know you cannot do like this

```
<?php lavada_query_item("category=<?php echo lavada_category_id() ; ?>");?>
```

But how can I do it?

Comment: `lavada_query_item("category=" . lavada_category_id());`

Comment: post the function code for `lavada_category_id()`

Comment: You cannot use one extra `<?php` tag inside another `<?php` tag. This will generate PHP syntax error. Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: <?php lavada_query_item("category=".lavada_category_id()); ?> 

http://www.php5-tutorial.com/data-types/working-with-strings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to concatenate the string like this:

```
<?php lavada_query_item("category=". lavada_category_id() );?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not store it into a variable and then use that variable?

```
<?php 
    $catID = lavada_category_id();
    lavada_query_item("category={$catID}");
 ?>
```

OR if you just want category ID to be passed into lavada_query_item do this:

```
lavada_query_item($catID);
```

The syntax error that you have is that you can not use `<?php` within `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php lavada_query_item(lavada_category_id());?>
```

The value returned from thelavada_category_id() function will be passed into the lavada_query_item() function.